# How to add placeholder from the localization text in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, localization

I have a search box i want to make its placeholder text changes on language changes.I have added asp-for its working for normal text but not working for the placeholder.

```
<label asp-for="textt" ></label>
```

above showing code is working now need to change text of the

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="need to change this text">
```

Comment: Consult the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1#view-localization) its very well documented feature

Comment: @Tseng thanks for response but i am not able to find anything related to the change plachoder

Comment: placeholder attribute is no different than any other piece of html, nothing is different

Comment: but if i user asp-for it is not working for placeholder

Comment: are you injecting IViewLocalizer to your views?

Comment: `placeholder="@Localizer["Foo"]"` is not working??? With Foo being defined in your resource files to be translated to the language specific meaning? Can't be, just tested. Documentation is so clear on how to use view localization here

Comment: @Tseng does that actually work? The documentation doesn't mention any single html attribute substitution.

Comment: @reckface: Not sure I can follow. the `placeholder` is an html attribute for the floating text and you can inject a view localizer into your views with like `@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer` and access it  via `@Localizer["Foo"]`

Comment: @tseng in the docs, there's no html attribute example. For example: Is it `placeholder="@Localizer["Foo"]"` or `"placeholder='@Localizer["Foo"]'` because the editors can't seem to colour it correctly. I am commenting on the docs. Because we can **just** try it.

Comment: Why should be there a special remarks to that? `@Localizer["Foo"]"` produces a regular string that is replaced once the template is run. Its in on way different than assigning content or a variable to an attribute

Answer (score 2):

For placeholder localization, you could try [DataAnnotations localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2#dataannotations-localization).

Follow Steps below:

1. Model in `Models Folder`

   ```
       namespace LocalizationPro.Models
       {
           public class LocalizationVM
           {
               public int Id { get; set; }
               public string Name { get; set; }
               [Display(Name = "Email", Prompt = "example@outlook.com")]
               public string Email { get; set; }
           }
       }
   ```
2. Resource File with name `Models.LocalizationVM.en.resx` under `Resources Folder`.

**Note**, the resource file name indicates the model location without project namespace.

Here is a official demo:

[Localization](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/localization/sample/Localization).